# From customer purchases dates by ID to purchase interval in days by ID in python

Tags: python, date, dataframe, intervals

I have a dataframe in Python contains the customer purchase recordes:

```
CUST_ID    CUST_PURCHASE_DATE
0001       20140204
0001       20150102
0002       20150411
0002       20160201
0002       20160302
.....
```

I wish to get:

```
CUST_ID    CUST_PURCHASE_DATE    CUST_PURCHASE_INTERVALS
0001       20140204              0
0001       20150102              331
0002       20150411              0
0002       20160201              302
0002       20160302              30
.....
```

How can I do this in Python with DataFrame maniputlation?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your column to a proper datetime, group by CUST_ID and `.diff()` them, eg:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.CUST_PURCHASE_DATE, format='%Y%m%d').groupby(df.CUST_ID).diff().fillna(0)
```

Gives you:

```
0     0 days
1   332 days
2     0 days
3   296 days
4    30 days
Name: CUST_PURCHASE_DATE, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```